# What is the difference between makeExecutableSchema & buildClientSchema in Apollo GraphQL

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-tools

I'm trying to build a mocking infrastructure for our react client. Getting confused between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[buildClientSchema](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#buildclientschema) vs [makeExecutableSchema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html#makeExecutableSchema)

- *makeExecutableSchema* can be used to mock schema types, resolvers, logger, etc...
- *buildClientSchema*  can only be used to mock the schema types, but cannot be used to execute queries/mutations.

If you want to mock and test the return (query) data use *makeExecutableSchema* if is just to test the schema type definitions use *buildClientSchema*.

It always comes into what you need to test.

Comment: Ahh got it, so a combination of `buildClientSchema` & `addMockFunctionsToSchema` would suffice in the client to achieve both mocking of schema tips and queries/mutations right? Thanks for the response @MarcoDaniels.